# how this "and" function in sql works?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
select *
from employement 
where emp_addr = 'varanasi' and emp_addr = 'delhi'
```

if all the conditions separated by and are true then it will display records but here both the conditions are true still am not getting anything?

Comment: share the data and table as well

Comment: how one column contain two data?.. show your data..

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause is specifying that a column in a given record simultaneously has *two* different values:

```
where emp_addr = 'varanasi' and emp_addr = 'delhi'
```

This is impossible, so you always get back no result set.  Perhaps you intended to `OR` together these criteria:

```
where emp_addr = 'varanasi' or emp_addr = 'delhi'
```

Or, perhaps you want to find all groups of records which have both these addresses present:

```
SELECT some_col
FROM yourTable
WHERE emp_addr IN ('varanasi', 'delhi')
GROUP BY some_col
HAVING MIN(emp_addr) <> MAX(emp_addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`

```
select * from employement where emp_addr in ('varanasi','delhi')
```

Answer (score 0):

How can emp_addr='varanasi' and emp_addr='delhi'? No records will ever match.